# OCMock - Mocking class method?

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

I'm trying to mock a class method, and it doesn't seem to be working as expected. any thoughts?

```
@implementation ApplicationVersionManager

+ (NSString *)appVersion {
   return [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
}

@end
```

Test

```
- (void)testSomething {
   OCMStub([ApplicationVersionManager appVersion]).andReturn(@"3.0");
   NSString *version = [ApplicationVersionManager appVersion];
   // version is nil. Why?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While OCMock can stub methods on existing objects, you still need a mock object to set up the stubs. The following should work:

```
- (void)testSomething {
   id mock = OCMClassMock([ApplicationVersionManager class]);
   OCMStub([mock appVersion]).andReturn(@"3.0");
   NSString *version = [ApplicationVersionManager appVersion];
}
```